# How to upload image or file and display it in Custom Module using form field in Magento 2

Tags: image-upload

Hello everyone in my case I want to add an image field in a custom form inside a custom module I have already the crud worked fine with the other fields like file_id,name,created_at updated_at, but I don't know how to add the field 'logo', and what files I have to change.

> if anyone can help me please I will be appreciated ?

Comment: Please check and update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Add new column into InstallSchema.php for image**

```
->addColumn(
            'img',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => true],
            'Image'
        )
```

> **Add Form type must be this**

***enctype="multipart/form-data" : No characters are encoded. This value is required when you are using forms that have a file upload control.***

```
$form = $this->_formFactory->create(
    ['data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                    'method' => 'post'
                ]
    ]
);
```

> **Add field into your form**

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'img',
        'image', 
        [
            'name' => 'img',
            'label' => __('Upload Image'),
            'title' => __('Upload Image'),
            'required' => true,
            'note' => 'Allow image type: jpg, jpeg, png',
            'class' => 'required-entry required-file',
        ]
    );
```

> **For Save Image**

```
    protected $fileSystem;

    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $adapterFactory;


    public function __construct(
        .............................................
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $fileSystem,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        .............................................
    ) {
        .............................................
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        .............................................
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        /* for delete image */

        if (isset($data['img']['delete'])) {
            if ($data['img']['delete'] == 1) {
                $data['img'] = '';
            }
        }

        /* for upload image */
        if ((isset($_FILES['img']['name'])) && ($_FILES['img']['name'] != '') && (!isset($data['img']['delete']))) {
            try
            {
                $uploaderFactory = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'img']);
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
                $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
                $uploaderFactory->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploaderFactory->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $mediaDirectory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $destinationPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('Vendorename_ModuleName_IMG');

                //echo "<br/>destination path".$destinationPath;

                $result = $uploaderFactory->save($destinationPath);

                // print_r($result);

                if (!$result) {
                    throw new LocalizedException
                        (
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );

                }

                $imagePath = 'Vendorename_ModuleName_IMG' . $result['file'];

                //echo "<br/> Image store ".$imagePath;

                $data['img'] = $imagePath;


            } // try block
             catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__("Image not Upload Pleae Try Again"));
            }

        }

        .............................................
        .............................................

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data)
        exit();

  }
}
```

> **For show image into Grid**

```
    <column name="img" class="Vendorename\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                   <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                   <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">store image</item>
                   <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
              <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
              <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
   </column>
```

**Vendorename\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column**

**Thumbnail.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendorename\Modulename\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
    const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        Image $imageHelper,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if(isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $url = '';
                if($item[$fieldName] != '') {
                    $url = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
                    ).$item[$fieldName];
                }
                $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $url;
                $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
                $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('routename/controllername/actionname',['id' => $item['id']]);
                $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $url;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

    protected function getAlt($row)
    {
        $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
        return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
    }
}
```

> **Run Magento command**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento c:c
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: thank you for your response it worked like the charm, but not for the delete option

Comment: and what link should i ut here , is for ndex or edit                 $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('myroute/items/index',['id' => $item['id']]);

Comment: also when i click on the save button when i edit the item , it add a new identical item from the one which i was edited , have you any ideas please ?